# ASP.NET Core 2 - Angular & JWT Authentication

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, jwt, nswag

**Problem**: I seem unable to fetch the `User` or any user-related data (e.g. `UserID`) in any controller after the token has been recorded to browser local storage.

I've set a breakpoint and studied `HttpContext` member of `ControllerBase` instance (the client app makes request + the `auth_token` is kept in local storage at this stage).

You only can extract the referrer url from `Headers` but there's no info about `tokens`.

*Even if you create a cookie for the token - the `Request` doesn't have it (0 cookies found at all).*

Perhaps I misunderstand the concept of how authorization works.

Here's the bit I misunderstand most - how does `ASP.NET Core` fetch the `token` from the request made by client app - it must be kept in headers?

Also, could anyone share a working example of JWT Authentication where `Angular` & `ASP.NET Core` are separate solutions?

I've implemented **login functionality** and I store the access token in browser local storage.

```
this._authService.authenticate(this.loginModel)
  .finally(finallyCallback)
  .subscribe((result: AuthenticateOutput) => {
     localStorage.setItem('auth_token', result.token);
});
```

Must the name of the token be in accordance with any conventions? (I wonder if `auth_token` is appropriate in this case.)

`SessionController` - the method which fetches current user info:

```
public async Task<GetCurrentLoginDetailsOutput> GetCurrentLoginDetails()
{
    var output = new GetCurrentLoginDetailsOutput();
    var user = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
    if (user != null)
    {
        output.User = Mapper.Map<UserDto>(user);
        output.Tenant = Mapper.Map<TenantDto>(user.Tenant);
    }
    return output;
}
```

In my `Authenticate` method of `AuthContoller` I create Claim which holds UserID:

```
var user = await _userService.Authenticate(input.UserName, input.Password);

var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Issuer = _config.GetValidIssuer(),
    Audience = _config.GetValidAudience(),
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(_config.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256),
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
    {
         new Claim("id", user.Id.ToString())
    })
};
```

`_userService.Authenticate` method fetches the user and checks if the password is correct as follows:

```
var user = _context.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName == username);

if (user == null) { return null; }

bool correctPassword = await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password);
```

JWT config in `Startup.cs`

```
services
   .AddAuthentication()
   .AddJwtBearer(x =>
   {
      x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
      x.SaveToken = true;
      x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
      {
          IssuerSigningKey = Configuration.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(),
          ValidAudience = Configuration.GetValidAudience(),
          ValidIssuer = Configuration.GetValidIssuer()
      };
});
```

`CORS` is configured as follows:

```
.AllowAnyOrigin()
.AllowAnyHeader()
.AllowAnyMethod()
.AllowCredentials()
```

Additional info:

- The Angular app is a separate solution / project - not the "one solution" template available in `VS2017`.
- I'm using `ASP.NET Core v2.1`
- I'm using NSwag.AspNetCore package to auto-generate services for Angular project.
- Here's the [tutorial](https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login) which I've been using to code my app.

Comment: Typically the JWT would be sent to the backend either in a cookie, or in a header, yes. In the example you've linked to, they send it in the "Authorization" header

Comment: Why does your method have [AllowAnonymous] if you need user data at that point?

Comment: good point @AlexRiabov, will investigate this bit, thank you!